# Why are my users not able to verify their email address?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email, uniqueidentifier

I'm using a `uniqueidentifier` to validate the email address of a user in my ASP.NET application. When I try to validate any email address using the `uniqueidentifier`, I can do so without problem. 80% of my users, however, cannot do so. I cannot figure out why this is happening! I've had users email me directly, forwarding their activation email and I can activate their account without issue.

Here's an example of the validation link that's in the email.

> mysite.org/petition.aspx?uid=0fcc9582-386c-4738-943d-36e09c8df4bd

Here's the exception that's occurring:

```
problem loading petition screen: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).:
    at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
     at System.Guid.TryParseGuidWithDashes(String guidString, GuidResult& result)
     at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
     at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
     at MAP.Umbraco.UserControls.SignPetitionUserControl.get_PetitionGuid()
     at MAP.Umbraco.UserControls.SignPetitionUserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

**UPDATE:** Here's the get method for my PetitionGuid property.

```
private Guid? PetitionGuid
        {
            get
            {
                if (Page.Request.QueryString["uid"] == null)
                    return null;
                else
                    return new Guid( Page.Request.QueryString["uid"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing here?

Feel free to ask any questions that you might need to ask.

Comment: Are you converting url parameter string to guid?

Comment: How are you generating the `guid` values in the first place?

Comment: @kad1r Yes, I'm converting from string to guid. I've updated the question with the accessor method for my Guid property.

@shree.pat18 I'm generating the GUID using the `Guid.NewGuid()` method. This appears to be working just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a character.

```
0fcc9582-386c-4738-943d-36e09c8df4b   <---
12345678 1234 1234 1234 123456789012
```

**Update**

Based on your update above, your implementation for petition guid is not coded very defensively.

```
private Guid? PetitionGuid
    {
        get
        {
            if (Page.Request.QueryString["uid"] == null)
                return null;
            else
                return new Guid( Page.Request.QueryString["uid"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

so basically, if the `uid` parameter is ANYTHING other than null, (a number, random string, other garbage) you are going to try and turn it into a guid. and that's obviously causing failures... put some logging in, and record the values of UID that are being submitted.

You should probably be using something like tryParse, instead of just puking an exception.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    Console.WriteLine("Null or Empty");

Guid g; 
Guid.TryParse(s, out g);

if(g == Guid.MinValue)
    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Parse");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("G: {0}", g);
```

Comment: This is not actually the problem. I missed out on the last character when pasting. I've updated the question now.

Comment: The only way you are getting that particular error is if you are not passing valid guids so either the guids have the wrong length of chars, dashes removed, non-hex characters swapped in or something or other crap appended onto them, or your users are copy pasting the URL and missing chars themselves... YMMV

Comment: Hey Eoin, thanks for the insight. Maybe it'd be good to use something other than guids then? Maybe a shortened hash of the guid?

Comment: I don't think that's it... Guid's are fine themselves... I'd just change your code a little as per my "tryparse" suggestion above, and in the case where you can't parse them, present the user with a more explanatory error rather than a stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

`Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)`
Does tihs `0fcc9582-386c-4738-943d-36e09c8df4b` meet to requirement? You lost one digit in last part. You have 11 digit instead of 12.

Comment: This is not actually the problem. I missed out on the last character when pasting. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current answers and comments and the fact that you use Umbraco I supect the QueryString is delivered to you in an encoded form. Better make sure that what we get is sane and valid and in the format we can actually handle it. The main improvement is in usimg [`HttpUtility.Decode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the querystring into shape.

```
private Guid? PetitionGuid
{
    get
    {
        Guid? guid = null;
        var raw = Page.Request.QueryString["uid"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(raw))
        {
            var decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(raw);
            Guid parsed;
            if (Guid.TryParse(decoded, out parsed))
            {
                guid = parsed;
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format(
                    "illigal uid {0}:{1}", raw,decoded)); 
            }
        }
        return guid;
    }
}
```